# How to Get HTML Tables Values and assign into Select and Input Text Fields?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I hope you all of fine, I've been facing problem to get data from HTML tables into Select Box.

I'm using Php MySQLi and Ajax Using Jquery to Perform the operations such as Insert, Update, Delete and View. I completed two processes such as Insert, and Display Data on the Tables, But I can't getting HTML tables and to assign in HTML Tags Select Box.

I have used Foreign Key References to Make Relationship between Category and Also Product Tables. I want to get **Category_Name**  from product table and assign a selected category_name into HTML Select Box.

**Here is Php Function**

```html
 // Get Product Data
       function get_product_record()
       {
        global $con;
        $Pro_Update_Id = $_POST['Pro_Update_ID'];
        $query = "select * from product where Product_ID='$Pro_Update_Id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data = "";
            $data[0]=$row['Product_ID'];
            $data[1]=$row['Category_ID'];
            $data[2]=$row['Product_Name'];
            $data[3]=$row['Product_Qty'];
            $data[4]=$row['Price'];
            $data[5]=$row['Description'];
        }
            echo json_encode($data);
       }
```

**Here is jQuery File**

```html
function get_pro_record()
{
    $(document).on('click','#p_btn_edit',function()
    {
        var GetPID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'includes/products/get_pro_record.php',
                method: 'post',
                data:{Pro_Update_ID:GetPID},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#product_id').val(data[0]);
                    $('#cat_up_id').val(data[1]);
                    $('#product_up_name').val(data[2]);
                    $('#up_Qty').val(data[3]);
                    $('#up_Price').val(data[4]);
                    $('#up_description').val(data[5]);
                    $('#products_update').modal('show');
                }
            })
    })
}
```

**Here is HTML Form **

```html
<form>
 <input type="hidden" id="product_id" class="form-control my-2" placeholder=" Product Name">
 <select name="cat_up_id"></select>
 <input type="text" id="product_up_name" class="form-control my-2" placeholder=" Product Name">
 <input type="text" id="up_Qty" class="form-control my-2" placeholder=" QTY">
 <input type="text" id="up_Price" class="form-control my-2" placeholder=" Price ">
 <textarea id="up_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
 </form>
```

I'm receiving complete data into console screen, but I can't see category_name I'm receiving category_id. So Please tell me What Can I do to solve the problem.

**Here is Output of the Project in Console**
[Project Output in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mIO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to query database from both Product and Category table using Inner Join

```
$query = "select a.*, b.Category_Name from product a, category b where a.Category_Id = 
          b.Category_Id and Product_ID='$Pro_Update_Id'";
```

then you need to add $data with one more element for Category Name

```
 $data[6]=$row['Category_Name'];
```

then you need to add options item to select

```
 $('#cat_up_id').html('<option>' + data[6] + '</option>');
```

and, replace attribute name="cat_up_id" with id="cat_up_id" in select tag

Comment: Hey There Thanks A Lot, but I faced another problem after getting complete records in the form, I want to display another categories, in this time, I can see only selected categories. Anyone users will able to change the category to update the record. How?

Answer (score 0):

Sonal Bonkar is correct you need to make table joins here is some correction In your case as you need to have value as id to to store in table

```
$('#cat_up_id').html('<option value="'+ data[1] +'">' + data[6] + '</option>');
```

Comment: **Please Note:** `$('#cat_up_id').append('<option value="'+ data[1] +'">' + data[6] + '</option>'); ` will also work

Comment: Hey There Thanks A Lot, but I faced another problem after getting complete records in the form, I want to display another categories, in this time, I can see only selected categories. Anyone users will able to change the category to update the record. How?

Comment: I did not understand your question.. can you please post another question for this with your code.. and provide me the link of question here.

Comment: Hi Thanks A Lot please look at that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535053/how-to-display-categories-in-select-box